# Helper methods and properties not present, class seems instantiated

Tags: helper, configuration

NOTE: This appears to be compiler related.  Disabling and clearing compiler code appears to have worked to get this doing what it was supposed to.

So this one is a bit odd.  I'm sure it's old hat to some now, and I've just done a bad job searching it out.  If that's the case I certainly apologize and ask for your indulgence and a link to the already provided answer.

So I have followed the core guides for creating a magento module, but for some reason it does work right.  When I var_dump the helper class it has the correct name, but when I try to use one of the methods I've put in the class definition it throws an exception.

Furthermore, when I run `get_class_methods()` on the class given to me by `Mage::helper('mymodule/myhelper')` none of my methods are there.

So in summary:

1. The class is in the right place, app/code/local/MyModule/Helper/Myhelper.php
2. The class shows as initialized after I call `Mage::helper('mymodule/myhelper')`
3. The class methods are not listed, and as a result, break things when called.

Here's my config for reference.  The rest of the module seems to be fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
  <modules>
    <APCShared_Shipping>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </APCShared_Shipping>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <apcshipping>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>APCShared_Shipping</module>
          <frontName>apcshipping</frontName>
        </args>
      </apcshipping>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <apcshipping>
        <class>APCShared_Shipping_Block</class>
      </apcshipping>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
      <apcshipping>
        <class>APCShared_Shipping_Helper</class>
      </apcshipping>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <apcshipping>
        <class>APCShared_Shipping_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>shipping_resource</resourceModel>
      </apcshipping>
      <apcshipping_resource>
        <class>APCShared_Shipping_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
          <zipcode>
            <table>apc_shipping_zipcode</table>
          </zipcode>
        </entities>
      </apcshipping_resource>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Could you please update your examples with real code as mymodule/myhelper does not match your config.

Comment: So, sorry about the big todo, but it appears that this was compiler related.

Comment: The path of the file should be `app/code/local/APCShared/Shipping/Helper/Myhelper.php` it seems you forgot the namespace directory just above your extension directory

Answer (score 1):

You can try below ones

If your module is created perfectly and you have methods in myhelper.php  file look as below.

```
class Namespace_ModuleName_Helper_Myhelper extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
public function getModuleStatus()
    {                
       return 'testing';
    }
}
```

to access the getModuleStatus() method in any phtml of php file then you can use

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('mymodule')->getModuleStatus();?>
```

you defiantly got the value as a "testing".